# Local domain won't resolve

Tags: 14.04, networking, dns, avahi

I have a dns which I had put into the ip4 config which should in theory give me access to a *.test.local domain. It pings well.

I also disabled the avahi daemon completely. The hosts line in the nsswitch.conf now looks like:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns mdns4
```

Now, when I try to access any subdomain of *.test.local, I get nothing via browser. When I ping, everything is fine.

The SIP hub located at the sip.test.local doesn't connect via SIP client either (I use Zoiper), but also pings well.

How can this be fixed? My ubuntu version is 14.04.

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the the nsswitch.conf I write it so:

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```

In fact the word dns must be in a greater place than before. Your solution should works too.

It works for the ping immediately but **for your browser you need to close it** before. Just try when I just close and re-opened Firefox it still don't work, when I **close the session (disconnect from Ubuntu)** it works! (perhaps some cache somewhere in Firefox)